# how to fix accessibility for bootstrap overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

Trying to achieve the accessibility to overlay, but unable to achieve that.

Want heading should be read first when the overlay is opened and then corresponding tags should be read.
in the last the close should be read. and click of escape button the pop up should be closed and intimate the user that the pop is going to close.

How do achieve that. have used tab index but it doesn't help.

here is my DOM Structure.

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content text-center">
            <div class="modal-body">  
                <div id="show_main_heading">
                    <a href="#" class="" title="close"></a>
                    <h3 class="text-left" tabindex = "0" id="" tabindex = "-1">Header</h3>
                    <p class="text-left" tabindex = "1">Content or Description</p>
                    <p class="text-left" tabindex = "2"><label class="">*</label>required field</p>                 
                </div>              
                <form class="form-horizontal no-summary" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="firstName" class="col-md-12 text-left" aria-hidden="true" tabindex = "3">firstname</label>
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="text" tabindex = "4" aria-label="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="firstname" autocomplete="off">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                      
                    </div>              
                </form>
                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                <p class="error-message"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootsrap uses the escape() function to check if the keypressed is is 27, like so :

```
  Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
    if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
      this.$element.on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        e.which == 27 && this.hide()
      }, this))
    } else if (!this.isShown) {
      this.$element.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal')
    }
  }
```

This piece of code can be [found on GitHub too](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L149):

You probably want to be editing the code inside that function, something like below :

```
  Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
    if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) {
      this.$element.on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        e.which == 27 && this.hide()
        if (e.which == 27){
              // prompt if user if he really want to close the window . 
             if() // user says close window . 
             { this.hide() }
             else { return false; }
        }

      }, this))
    } else if (!this.isShown) {
      this.$element.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal')
    }
  }
```